# Event bubbling through parent controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have the following route

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('projects', {path: 'projects'}, function(){
      this.route('new', {path: 'new'});
      this.route('show', {path: ':project_id'});
      this.route('edit', {path: ':project_id/edit'});
  });  
});
```

I want all the events from 'ProjectsNewController', 'ProjectsShowController', 'ProjectsEditController' to bubble to 'ProjectsController'.

How can I attain this?
JSBin: http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1284/edit

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The way event bubbling works in ember is **not:**

```
ChildController -> Controller -> ParentController
```

but rather:

```
View -> Controller -> Route -> ApplicationRoute (optionally)
```

Therefore if an event is fired from the `view` it will bubble up to the `controller` and stop there, if the `controller` returns `true` from the event handler then it will continue to bubble up to the `route`. Events that are not handled in the `controller` nor the `route` will bubble all the way up to the `ApplicationRoute`.

To achieve what you want to do you should use the `needs` API to obtain access to the `ProjectsController` and send the events/actions to that `controller` using `.send(...)`.

For example:

```
App.ProjectsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions:{
    newProject: function() {
      console.log("ProjectsController:newProject");
    }
  }
});

App.ProjectsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['projects'],
  actions:{
    newProject: function() {
      console.log("ProjectsNewController:newProject");
      // forward action to ProjectsController
      this.get('controllers.projects').send('newProject');
    }
  }
});

App.ProjectsEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['projects'],
  actions:{
    newProject: function() {
      console.log("ProjectsEditController:newProject");
      // forward action to ProjectsController
      this.get('controllers.projects').send('newProject');
    }
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Bubbling in router goes through entire route hierarchy up to the application route. So one action can be handled by multiple nested routes if their handlers bubble (return true).